# Почему MySQLi не хочет фетчить  данные в массив?

Tags: mysqli, php

```
    if ($query = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `id`=?"))
    {

        $query->bind_param("i",$this->id);
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $query->free();
        $query->close();

        var_dump($result);

    }
```

в итоге ошибка:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined
> method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что у класса mysqli_stmt нет метода fetch_array(). Он есть у класса mysqli_result.

```
 $result = $query->get_result()->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

[Читайте доки](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.mysqli-stmt.php)

Comment: спасибо, а что-то не туда смотрел наверное, тоже в документации искал ответ и набрел на это http://php.su/functions/?mysqli-fetch-array, результат вы уже поняли какой.